# setting hibernate with wildfly8

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, migration, wildfly

I'm working on a web project with tomcat 7 hibernate  and I want to migrate to wildfly8 .I made some modification on my project and now I can deploy it without errors but when I try to access data base to login i get the following error

```
09:37:21,977 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (default task-4) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
09:37:21,982 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (default task-4) HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false}
09:37:21,984 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (default task-4) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
09:37:22,101 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (default task-4) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
09:37:22,493 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (default task-4) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
09:37:22,531 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (default task-4) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
09:37:22,571 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (default task-4) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.0.Final
09:37:22,767 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-4) UT005023: Exception handling request to /trytest/start.html: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55) [hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39) [hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at com.test.dao.GenericDAO.<clinit>(GenericDAO.java:12) [classes:]
    at com.user.façade.Loginff.<init>(Loginff.java:10) [classes:]
    at com.test.lanagedbeans.loginMb.loginAdmin(loginMb.java:37) [classes:]
    at com.test.servlets.Login.doPost(Login.java:48) [classes:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
```

and here is GenericDAO.java class

```
package com.test.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;

abstract class GenericDAO<T> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hibernate");
    private EntityManager em;

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public void beginTransaction() {
        em = emf.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    public void commit() {
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void rollback() {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    }

    public void closeTransaction() {
        em.close();
    }

    public void commitAndCloseTransaction() {
        commit();
        closeTransaction();
    }

    public void flush() {
        em.flush();
    }

    public void joinTransaction() {
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.joinTransaction();
    }

    public GenericDAO(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public void save(T entity) {
        em.persist(entity);
    }

    protected void delete(Object id, Class<T> classe) {
        T entityToBeRemoved = em.getReference(classe, id);

        em.remove(entityToBeRemoved);
    }

    public T update(T entity) {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }

    public T find(int entityID) {
        return em.find(entityClass, entityID);
    }

    public T findReferenceOnly(int entityID) {
        return em.getReference(entityClass, entityID);
    }

    // Using the unchecked because JPA does not have a
    // em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery()<T> method
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public List<T> findAll() {
        CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    // Using the unchecked because JPA does not have a
    // query.getSingleResult()<T> method
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected T findOneResult(String namedQuery, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        T result = null;

        try {
            Query query = em.createNamedQuery(namedQuery);

            // Method that will populate parameters if they are passed not null and empty
            if (parameters != null && !parameters.isEmpty()) {
                populateQueryParameters(query, parameters);
            }

            result = (T) query.getSingleResult();

        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            System.out.println("No result found for named query: " + namedQuery);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while running query: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void populateQueryParameters(Query query, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
            query.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="hibernate" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 

        <jta-data-source>java:/hibernate</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="21239209" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.shutdown" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="false" />
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.adapterModule"value="org.hibernate" /> 

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

this was working perfectly with tomcat7.

 Thanks

Comment: There are very slight differences for servlets between Tomcat 7 and Wildfly 8.  Tomcat 7 implements the Servlet 3.0 specification and Wildfly 8 implements 3.1.  However, the differences for most applications should be minimal.  I'd take a look in your logs for any messages (in the standalone/log directory in the Wildfly installation directory) and start there.

Comment: thanks for your answer stdunbar but it seems that the problem comms from database access